# Trouble choosing a sorting key for a text file

Tags: sort

Suppose I have a text file like this:

```
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9                       "Biswas Gautam"                   2016            me            Mob
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12                       "Dipin Gyawali"                   2015            me            Lan
f0:27:65:70:91:62                       "Karan Rai"                       2016            cs            Mob
f0:de:f1:33:33:32                       "Dipendra L. Karki"               2015            me            Lan
```

I want to sort it by the third column (years) and by 4th column with batch like me (mechanical engineering) & cs(computer science) & third by name

But the second column name is creating problem; sometimes they have a middle name, which conflicts with my initial solution. So I thought double quotes can solve problem. But I don't have any idea how to ignore space inside double quotes.

```
sort -k 4 -k 5 -k 2 -kfilename
```

I wrote 4 because there will be three spaces, one due to column and one due to full name (Name[space]Surname)

Is there any way to sort such things?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry i already changed it . It was due to 1 password manager pasting in title while loggin

Comment: Are the delimiters between the column tabs or spaces?

Comment: @Kusalananda that was just simple spaces. I choose so it looks preety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/ {3,}/@/g' file | sort -t @ -k3,3 -k5,5 | sed 's/@/    /g'
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12    "Dipin Gyawali"    2015    me    Lan
f0:de:f1:33:33:32    "Dipendra Karki"    2015    me    Lan
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9    "Biswas Gautam"    2016    me    Mob
f0:27:65:70:91:62    "Karan Rai"    2016    cs    Mob
```

This replaces any run of three or more spaces with the character `@` (any character that is not present in the data will work).

Then, `sort` is instructed to interpret its input as `@`-delimited fields and sorts on the 3rd field (year) and 5th field (device).  The final `sed` replace each `@` in the sorted data with four spaces (you may choose to insert a literal tab here instead, or `\t` with GNU `sed`).

Prettier:

```
$ sed -E 's/ {3,}/@/g' file | sort -t @ -k3,3 -k5,5 | column -s @ -t
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12  "Dipin Gyawali"   2015  me  Lan
f0:de:f1:33:33:32  "Dipendra Karki"  2015  me  Lan
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9  "Biswas Gautam"   2016  me  Mob
f0:27:65:70:91:62  "Karan Rai"       2016  cs  Mob
```

The following uses `awk` to format each column as a left-justified 20 characters wide string:

```
$ sed -E 's/ {3,}/@/g' file | sort -t @ -k3,3 -k5,5 | awk -F@ '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf("%-20s",$i); print "" }'
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12   "Dipin Gyawali"     2015                me                  Lan
f0:de:f1:33:33:32   "Dipendra Karki"    2015                me                  Lan
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9   "Biswas a Gautam"   2016                me                  Mob
f0:27:65:70:91:62   "Karan Rai"         2016                cs                  Mob
```

Or, you can format them individually:

```
$ sed -E 's/ {3,}/@/g' file | sort -t @ -k3,3 -k5,5 | awk -F@ '{ printf("%s %-30s %-30s %-30s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5) }'
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12 "Dipin Gyawali"                2015                           me                             Lan
f0:de:f1:33:33:32 "Dipendra Karki"               2015                           me                             Lan
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9 "Biswas a Gautam"              2016                           me                             Mob
f0:27:65:70:91:62 "Karan Rai"                    2016                           cs                             Mob
```

Comment: Formatting lost ?

Comment: @aftershock Yes, since we can't keep track of the column properly.  But I'll fix that soon (or not. It's tricky).

Comment: hmm isn't it possible just to change row without touching any columns?

like in this example the correct row is 4,2,3,1 First year then batch like me and last by name

Comment: @aftershock I've fixed the formatting, but I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment at all.

Comment: @aftershock I suppose someone might come along with a complex way of doing it all in `awk` that wouldn't touch the space between the columns, but I'm not that person.

Comment: i guess its fixed for two name but if there is middle name it has problems . is \t compulsory in last filter

Comment: @aftershock Could you please add an example to the text of the question? It's difficult to develop against imaginatory data. I've tested this by inserting extra bits of names for the ones already in the file, and "it works for me".

Comment: @Kusalananda Errr... why are you using `sed` to turn `@` to `\t` instead of just `column -s@` — am I missing something?

Comment: @derobert Ah. I was just using the first variation of the solution and tagging `column` on to that. You are right, I will fix that.

Comment: Can we add two or more than three tabs? so there will be more space between each columns? I tried adding \t\t\t but i guess there is no effect

Comment: @aftershock Sorry, I can't parse that first question. "at"?

Comment: i mean can we add space between columns or may be three tabs.

Comment: @aftershock Ah, "add".  You want to insert more space between the columns. Hold on.

Comment: @aftershock Fixed. You may then use any `printf` format you wish.

Comment: @Kusalananda Finally Done with full documentation! Thanks. It was great reading varieties of solutions . I hope it will help others also :)

Comment: why use @ rather than a tab?

Comment: @cas Any character that is not part of the data.

Comment: yeah, but tabs are the default, or at least commonly-used, separator for most text utilities.  i was just wondering if there was some particular reason not to use tabs.

Comment: @cas It's easier to type a `@`. Depending on shell and the type of `sed` used, a tab would have to be literal, a C-string `$'\t'` thing, or a `\t`, and it would be awkward to use and display properly here.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is strictly formatted (as displayed), you could ask `sort` to use specific columns for the keys:

```
sort -k1.75,1.78n -k1.91,1.92 -k1.105,1.107 -k1.41,1.74 input
```

... which transforms the sample input into:

```
f0:de:f1:33:33:32                       "Dipendra Karki"                  2015            me            Lan
ec:8e:b5:f8:a2:12                       "Dipin Gyawali"                   2015            me            Lan
f0:27:65:70:91:62                       "Karan Rai"                       2016            cs            Mob
e8:b4:c8:b2:d8:b9                       "Biswas Gautam"                   2016            me            Mob
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the spacing exactly (instead of reformat it, like in [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426136/977)) and don't want to depend on the exact column positions (like in [Jeff Schaller's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426140/977)), something like this Perl script will work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.022;

my @dat;
while (<<>>) {
    #          0     1      2        3     4     5     6     7     8
    #          mac   sp     name     sp    yr    sp    dpt   sp    net
    my @m = /^(\S+) (\s+) "([^"]+)" (\s+) (\S+) (\s+) (\S+) (\s+) (\S+)$/x
        or die "invalid line: $_";
    push @dat, \@m;
}

@dat = sort {
    $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] || $a->[6] cmp $b->[6] || $a->[2] cmp $b->[2]
} @dat;

foreach (@dat) {
    print join('', @$_), "\n";
}
```

Note that uses Perl v5.22.0 or later for the `<<>>` operator; it should work with positively ancient versions of Perl if you use `<>` instead. The program has essentially three "paragraphs": the first one parses your lines using a regexp, also capturing the exact spacing used. The second paragraph sorts the data. The third paragraph prints it back out.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to replace each space character *between* quotes with the placeholder character @, then do the sort, then change the @ characters back to spaces:

```
perl -pe 's#("[^"]*")#$1 =~ s/ /@/rg#eg' filename | sort -k 3 -k 4 -k 2 | sed 's/@/ /g'
```

Comment: As the [OP commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426133/trouble-choosing-a-sorting-key-for-a-text-file#comment768357_426136) on an [earlier version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426136/117549) of this idea, this loses the formatting/alignment.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I quite follow. This approach doesn't add or remove spaces. Every line in the original file is intact, the only difference is the order of the lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I misunderstood; I see now that you're replacing spaces in-between quotes; sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No probs. Just realized something else though -- it wasn't restoring the " characters; fixed now :-)